# Creating simple web page associating image with excel column

Tags: html, database

I have an excel page with columns such as:

Col Col2 Col3
abc  1    3
def  4    5
hgi  9    5

and so on.

And I have various images in a folder with file names corresponding to 'Col' i.e. abc.jpg, def.jpg, etc.

I want to create a webpage with asks for a string from a user, searches it in Col1, then displays corresponding Col2, Col3, and the image corresponding to that Col1.

NOW, I'm not asking for what to do, but I just want to know HOW will I do this? What all tools/scripts/languages/software do I need to know to implement a system like this? I'll get to learning that straight away.

I have very little experience in web development hence a very noob-ish question.

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have the user enter the information on the Webpage itself, I would recommend JavaScript. JavaScript is a good enough language to do the stuff you want to do. For accessing Excel, you could always export the Excel file as a CSV (Comma Separated Values) or another format and read into your JavaScript. You can read a file in your JavaScript code using [this link](http://www.ehow.com/how_5996745_read-file-html-script-javascript.html#page=0), for example.

Comment: The linked code is absolutely bogus. There are no `fopen`, `flength`, `fread` functions in any JavaScript implementation I know, even less in browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Just another thing, is Javascript required to do this advanced-level? For someone who hasn't done Javascript before, how long would it take to learn till this level? 
Hope the question isn't too specific. Just give your best approximation.